# MongoDB JSON Document formatting

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and I'm having some trouble storing documents in the JSON format to my database. I am provided with a test suite for my application but I'm unable to get one specific test to pass, because of the formatting of my document (I assume).
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Syn

This is the assertion that keeps failing:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :{ "log_set" : ["SCHEDULED", "STREAMING", "CANCELED", "FINISHED"] }
Actual   :Document{{log_set=[SCHEDULED, STREAMING, CANCELED, FINISHED]}}
```

Here is my code for inserting data:

```
@Override
public void loadData() throws Exception {
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("dst");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("EventData");

    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery(Constants.Q_ALLFINISHEDEVENTS);
    List<EventImpl> finishedEvents= query.getResultList();
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    for(int i=0; i<finishedEvents.size(); i++){
        Document toInsert = new Document("event_id",finishedEvents.get(i).getId());
        toInsert.append(Constants.PROP_EVENTFINISHED,finishedEvents.get(i).getEventStreaming().getEnd().getTime());
        toInsert.append(mongoTestData.getDataDescription(finishedEvents.get(i).getId()),mongoTestData.getData(finishedEvents.get(i).getId()));

        System.out.println("DATE ENDED: "+finishedEvents.get(i).getEventStreaming().getEnd().getTime());

        toInsert.append(Constants.PROP_EVENTFINISHED,finishedEvents.get(i).getEventStreaming().getEnd().getTime());

        System.out.println("DOCUMENT TO INSERT:"+toInsert.toString());
        System.out.println("DOCUMENT JSON: " +toInsert.toJson());
        //collection.insertOne(toInsert);
        BasicDBObject dbObject = (BasicDBObject) JSON.parse(toInsert.toJson());
        collection.insertOne(new Document(dbObject));
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Added the test and test data:

Here is the test code:

```
@Test
    public void testMongoDataLoader() throws Exception {
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection(Constants.COLL_EVENTDATA);
        Map<Long, Document> docs = idMap(collection, d -> d.getLong(Constants.I_EVENT));
        List<IEvent> list = daoFactory.getEventDAO().findAll();

        assertFalse(list.isEmpty());
        assertEquals(list.size(), docs.size());

        for (IEvent relObj : list) {
            assertTrue(docs.containsKey(relObj.getId()));
            assertDataEquals(docs.get(relObj.getId()), relObj);
        }
    }
protected void assertDataEquals(Document document, IEvent relObj) {
        MongoTestData mongoTestData = new MongoTestData();

        assertEquals(
                document.getLong(Constants.PROP_EVENTFINISHED).longValue(),
                relObj.getEventStreaming().getEnd().getTime()
        );
        assertEquals(
                document.get(mongoTestData.getDataDescription(relObj.getId())),
                Document.parse(mongoTestData.getData(relObj.getId()))
        );
    }
```

Here is the MongoTestData:

```
public class MongoTestData {
    public static final String DATA_DESC_LOGS = "logs";
    public static final String DATA_DESC_MATRIX = "matrix";
    public static final String DATA_DESC_BLOCK = "alignment_block";

    private ArrayList<String> testData = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> testDataDesc = new ArrayList<>();

    public MongoTestData() {
        String s1 = "{ \"log_set\" : [\"SCHEDULED\", \"STREAMING\", \"CANCELED\", \"FINISHED\"] }";
        String s2 = "{ \"matrix_data\" : [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]}";
        String s3 = "{ \"alignment_nr\" : 0, \"primary\" : { "
                + " \"chromosome\" : \"chr11\", \"start\" : 3001012, \"end\" : 3001075 }, \"align\" : { "
                + " \"chromosome\" : \"chr13\", \"start\" : 70568380, \"end\" : 70568443 }, \"blastz\" : 3500, "
                + "seq : [\"TCAGCTCATAAATCACCTCCTGCCACAAGCCTGGCCTGGTCCCAGGAGAGTGTCCAGGCTCAGA\", "
                + "\"TCTGTTCATAAACCACCTGCCATGACAAGCCTGGCCTGTTCCCAAGACAATGTCCAGGCTCAGA\"] }";

        testData.add(s1);
        testData.add(s2);
        testData.add(s3);

        testDataDesc.add(DATA_DESC_LOGS);
        testDataDesc.add(DATA_DESC_MATRIX);
        testDataDesc.add(DATA_DESC_BLOCK);
    }

    public String getData(Long eventId) {
        return testData.get(eventId.intValue() % 3);
    }

    public String getDataDescription(Long eventId) {
        return testDataDesc.get(eventId.intValue() % 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know MongoDB that much but it seems that the data  should be inserted directly and not nested in a Document

Comment: Can you add the test case ?

Comment: @Veeram I added the test case, as well as some of the data on which the test is run.

Comment: I see you have commented out `collection.insertOne(toInsert);`. That looks correct to me. What problem did you face with the commented code ?

Comment: The exact same as I do now. That's what I also initially thought, before doing the whole `JSON.parse(toInsert.toJson())` thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your insert code to insert the data as `Document` ( key value pairs ) instead of raw json string.

Update `for loop` code to below. Please note the use of `Document.parse`

```
for(int i=0; i<finishedEvents.size(); i++){
      Document toInsert = new Document("event_id", finishedEvents.get(i).getId());
      toInsert.append(Constants.PROP_EVENTFINISHED, finishedEvents.get(i).getEventStreaming().getEnd().getTime());
      toInsert.append(mongoTestData.getDataDescription(finishedEvents.get(i).getId()), Document.parse(mongoTestData.getData(finishedEvents.get(i).getId())));
      collection.insertOne(toInsert);
 }
```

Comment: The test suite is provided, I am only in charge of the implementation, so I am unable to change the tests.

Comment: Updated answer. Please verify.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your test harness is expecting JSON but it's getting a Document instance. Since those 2 are not strictly equal, the comparison is failing. So I'd say that this is probably an issue with your test harness or how you're using it.